# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.OCRD' with unique index 'OCRD_ABS_ENTRY'. The duplicate key value is (1). The statement has been terminated.;
>
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.; An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.OCRD' with unique index 'OCRD_ABS_ENTRY'. The duplicate key value is (1). The statement has
>   been terminated.
>
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

It's an insert on DB

Comment: So your question is..? The error is literally telling you the problem here.

Comment: Look at the definition of the index OCRD_ABS_ENTRY.  This will tell you which Field you are having a problem with.  The error message is telling you that the value you are trying to insert is the value "1".  A unique index will prevent duplicate values for that column from being inserted.  So you will either need to a) change the value to something that is unique or b) change the index so that it doesn't have a unique constraint.   99% of the time the correct coarse of action will be a).

Answer (score 1):

- You have a column named "OCRD_ABS_ENTRY" which has an integrity
  constraint (unique key or primary key).
- You try to insert another entry with value "1" for OCRD_ABS_ENTRY
  column, which should be unique.
- Try to delete the constraint if it's not necessary, or to insert with
  another value.

Comment: I don't have column named "OCRD_ABS_ENTRY" it's autogenerate from db...my PK is CardCode

Comment: Ok I have a primary key...
row |primary_key| other columns
1    100001       ...
2    100002       ...
3    500000       ...

I try to insert a new record with primary_key 100003
From what I understand is trying to write the new record in row 1 and I do not understand the reason ...

Answer (score 1):

follow what @Florian already said.
Additional information

- insert values into tables with out mentioning value to primary field

Comment: Ok I have a primary key...
row |primary_key| other columns
1    100001       ...
2    100002       ...
3    500000       ...

I try to insert a new record with primary_key 100003
From what I understand is trying to write the new record in row 1 and I do not understand the reason ...

Comment: is your primary key auto incremented or not?

Comment: as you inserted 1 once so you are not allowed to again insert 1 in praimary key colum, duplicacy not allowed in primary key .it always will be unique

Comment: can u plz describe about your primary key and what is your dbms

Comment: Primary key is nvarchar dbms sql server

Comment: ok but if  I have primary key like 100,101 and 102...new primary key(103) is not duplicate...

Comment: in that case problem should be arised in times of insertion , you can check 1st is there that key already exist or not .if you wany i can help you via team viewer